# Insert hyperlinks to chapters in document to cells in a XWPFTable

Tags: java, hyperlink, xwpf

My program creates a word file with many chapters and subchapters.

I am trying now to add a table at the beginning of the document with three columns (column 1: list of chapters, column 2: list of subchapters and column 3: remains empty, it will be filled in by the user with a summary) and in the first two columns I want the text to be a hyperlink to the respective chapter/subchapter.

I added the table but I am having trouble with the hyperlinks. I found some code on how to insert an internal hyperlink. But the hyperlink is inserted directly after the chapter/subchapter. I want the text in the cell to be the hyperlink:

```
private static void addHyperlink(XWPFParagraph para, String text, String bookmark) {
    // Create hyperlink in paragraph
    CTHyperlink cLink = para.getCTP().addNewHyperlink();
    cLink.setAnchor(bookmark);
    // Create the linked text
    CTText ctText = CTText.Factory.newInstance();
    ctText.setStringValue(text);
    CTR ctr = CTR.Factory.newInstance();
    ctr.setTArray(new CTText[] { ctText });

    // Insert the linked text into the link
    cLink.setRArray(new CTR[] { ctr });
}

private static void writeParagraphToDocument(String chapterName, String subchapterName) {
    XWPFParagraph chapterParagraph = resultDocument.createParagraph();
    chapterParagraph.setStyle(heading1Style);
    XWPFParagraph subchapterParagraph = resultDocument.createParagraph();
    subchapterParagraph.setStyle(heading2Style);

    // code to add paragraph in document

    XWPFTableRow l_tableRow = m_summaryTable.createRow();
    l_tableRow.getCell(0).setText(chapterName);
    l_tableRow.getCell(1).setText(subchapterName);
    addHyperlink(chapterParagraph, chapterName, "nameOfParagraph");
    l_tableRow.getCell(2).setText("");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
private static void addHyperlink(XWPFParagraph p_paragraphCell, XWPFParagraph p_paragraphLink, String p_linkedText, String p_paragraphText) {
    // Create hyperlink in paragraph
    CTHyperlink cLink = p_paragraphLink.getCTP().addNewHyperlink();
    cLink.setAnchor(p_paragraphText);
    // Create the linked text
    CTText ctText = CTText.Factory.newInstance();
    ctText.setStringValue(p_linkedText);
    CTR ctr = CTR.Factory.newInstance();
    ctr.setTArray(new CTText[] { ctText });

    // Insert the linked text into the link
    cLink.setRArray(new CTR[] { ctr });

    p_paragraphCell.getCTP().setHyperlinkArray(new CTHyperlink[] { cLink });
    p_paragraphLink.getCTP().removeHyperlink(0);
}
```